# Is there something wrong in my book's derivation of work done on charge?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, potential, work, conventions

For finding potential at a point due to a +ve charge $(q)$, we find work done to move a unit +ve charge $(q_o)$ from infinity to that point in the presence of +ve charge $(q)$

Since both charges being +ve, the force would be repulsive and hence while bringing unit +ve charge $(q_o)$ from infinity to that position, the path would be against force field. Thus the work done **by force field** should be negative.

But the following calculation/derivation in my book shows that work done is positive:

$$W$$
$$=\int_\infty^r F.dr$$
$$=-\int_\infty^r F dr\\$$
(since path is against force field)
$$=-\int_\infty^r \frac{1}{r^{2}}dr\\$$
$$=-\left( {-\frac{1}{r}} \Big |_{\infty}^{r}\right)$$
$$={\frac{1}{r}} \Big |_{\infty}^{r}$$
$$=\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{\infty}$$
$$=\frac{1}{r}$$

Why is this contradiction? Where am I (or my book) wrong?

Comment: *"Thus work done should be negative"* - the work done *by* the field is negative but the work done by the force bringing the charge in is positive.

Comment: The work done by the electrostatic force will be negative whereas work done by the external agent to move the charge is positive

Comment: Will they be equal and opposite?

Comment: Ideally, assuming no change in KE, yes.

Comment: In the derivation, $F$ represents the electrostatic force and not the external force. That is why the path is against the field. So in the derivation, $W$ should represent work done by electrostatic force and not work done by external force. This is turning out to be positive while in reality, it should be negative.

Comment: I think there is some confusion about the work integral.  For simplicity assume a force $F_0\hat{x}$ where $F_0 \gt 0$.  The work done *by* the force due to a displacement $x_1 \rightarrow x_2$ is given by $$W_[12]=\int^{x_2}_{x_1}F_0dx=F_0(x_2-x_1)$$  Note that if $x_2 \gt x_1$, the path is 'forwards' towards increasing $x$ and in the direction of the force so the work done by the force is positive while if $x_2 \lt x_1$, the path is 'backwards' towards decreasing $x$ and *against* the direction of the force so the work done by the force is negative.  But we didn't change the integral.

Comment: The path is from $\infty$ towards $r$,i.e. 'backwards' towards decreasing $r$ and hence *against* the direction of force. Thus the second case, i.e.$x_2<x_1$ or $r<\infty$, is what is used in the derivation. So the work done should be negative. Instead the result is positive.

Comment: What book is that? Even better, can you upload an image?

Comment: Two comments to help prevent confusion:  1.) Potential and potential energy are defined in terms of the conservative force in question, *not* the force used to move the test charge.  This prevents confusion if there are other forces involved.  2.) Take the integral from $-\infty$ to $-r$.  This prevents confusion caused by the displacement going in the direction opposite to the coordinate system.  Try again with those two hints.

Answer (score -1):

The work done by the external force is in the direction of the force applied, hence work done by F(ext) is positive & at the same time work done by the electric field due to the positive charge (q) is negative since work is done against the direction of the force (as you say).

But,
$$  F_\text{ext}=-F_\text{electric field}$$

Therefore
$$W_\text{ext}=-W_\text{electric field}$$

The work done by force field is negative. Maybe you are confused with potential energy,
\begin{align}
PE&=W_\text{EXT}\\
&= ∫ F_\text{ext}.dr\\
&=“-“∫ F_\text{electric field}.dr\\
&= -W_\text{electric field}
\end{align}

Comment: I'm new to the app, so had a problem typing